# how to do assignment of numbers in r (one machine n jobs)

Tags: r

I am working on assignment problem in R. I have following dataframe in r

```
  cycle_time   TAT  ready_for_next  ITV_no    
        2      10        12          0           
        4      12        16          0           
        6      13        19          0           
        8      11        19          0           
       10      15        25          0           
       12      17        29          0           
       14      13        27          0           
       16      13        29          0           
       18      12        30          0             
       20      16        36          0
       22      13        35          0
       24      12        36          0
       26      15        41          0
       28      14        42          0
       30      17        47          0
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
  cycle_time   TAT  ready_for_next  ITV_no     wait_time
        2      10        12          1            0
        4      12        16          2            0
        6      13        19          3            0
        8      11        19          4            0
       10      15        25          5            0
       12      17        29          1            0 
       14      13        27          6            0
       16      13        29          2            0
       18      12        30          3            1
       20      16        36          4            1
       22      13        35          5            3
       24      12        36          6            3
       26      15        41          2            3 
       28      14        42          3            2 
       30      17        47          5            5

 cycle_time = crane cycle time
 TAT(in mins) = turn around time of truck
 ready_for_next(in mins) = ready to take next container
 ITV_no = ITV no to be assigned for that job

 ***There are only 6 unique trucks available***
```

Idea here is to assign trucks such that waiting time is minimum. 
In first five observations all 5 trucks are assigned.

For the next container i.e row number 6 (on 12th min) ITV_no 1 is coming back from its job so that will get assigned to this job. 
7th observation(i.e 14th min) there are no trucks available,so we will have to assign new truck (i.e ITV_no 6)
8th observation(16 min) ITV_no 2 is coming back from its job,so that will get assigned to this job and so on.

If there are no trucks available then it has to wait till the nearest truck comes back from job.

How can I implement this in R?

I have build some logic

```
cycle_time <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30)
ITV_no <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
temp <- c()
TAT <- c(10,12,13,11,15,17,13,13,12,16,13,12,15,14,17)
ready_for_next <- cycle_time + TAT

assignment <- data.frame(cycle_time,TAT,ready_for_next)
assignment$ITV_no <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(assignment)) {

   for(j in 1:length(ITV_no)){
       assignment$ITV_no[i] <- ifelse(assignment$cycle_time <= assignment$ready_for_next,ITV_no[j],
            ifelse())

 ## I am not able to update the count of trucks which are already assigned
 # and which are free to be assigned
 }
 }

Logic
1. first row increment ITV_no by 1. directly assign truck to that job
2. check if cycle_time <= previous all ready_for_next(i.e 12), if yes then increment ITV_no by 1,if no then assign previous ITV_no for that job(i.e 1)

e.g 
for row 6, cycle time will get compared to all previous ready_for_next column values (25,19,19,16,12) it finds the match at first row then that ITV_no(i.e 2) is assigned to 6th row
for row 7, cycle time will get compared to all previous ready_for_next column values (25,19,19,16) **12 should be removed from comparison because the truck is already assigned to the job** match at first row then that ITV_no(i.e 2) is assigned to 6th row. No match,so new truck is assigned to that job
```

Comment: Please lay out the full algorithm and how you are trying to implement it and where you get stuck.

Comment: Also, please share reproducible data (for example with `dput` or `df <- data.frame(...)`

Comment: reproducible data is already shared in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with some solution...
It is working with sample data

```
rm(list=ls())
df <- data.frame(qc_time =   seq(2,40,2),itv_tat=c(10,15,12,18,25,19,18,16,14,10,12,15,17,19,13,12,8,15,9,14))
itv_number_vec <- vector()
itv_number_vec <- 0

itvno_time <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{

  ####  Initialisation ####
    if (i==1)
    {
      df$itv_available_time[i] <- sum(df$qc_time[i] + df$itv_tat[i])
      itvno_time[[i]] <- df$itv_available_time[i]
      df$delay[i] <- 0
      df$itv_number[i] <- 1
      itv_number_vec <- 1
   }
    if(i!=1)
   {
    if (df$qc_time[i] >= min(unlist(itvno_time)))
  {
    for (j in 1:length(itvno_time))
    {

      if (itvno_time[[j]] <= df$qc_time[i])
      {
        df$itv_number[i] <- j
        df$itv_available_time[i] <- sum(df$qc_time[i] + df$itv_tat[i])
        itvno_time[[j]] <- df$itv_available_time[i]
        break
      }
    }
  }else{

          if (max(itv_number_vec)<7)
          {
            df$itv_number[i] <- max(itv_number_vec) + 1
            itv_number_vec <- c(itv_number_vec,(max(itv_number_vec) + 1))
            df$delay[i] <- 0
            df$itv_available_time[i] <- sum(df$qc_time[i] + df$itv_tat[i])
            itvno_time[[max(itv_number_vec)]] <- df$itv_available_time[i]
          }else{
                  df$delay[i] <- (min(unlist(itvno_time)) - df$qc_time[i])
                  df$itv_number[i] <- which.min(itvno_time)
                  df$itv_available_time[i] <- sum(df$qc_time[i], df$itv_tat[i] ,df$delay[i])
                  itvno_time[[which.min(itvno_time)]] <- df$itv_available_time[i] 
                }
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: Its working perfectly as I intended. I really appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks a ton.